# ¿Como concatenar cadenas con parametros en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string

```
var a;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayPath.length-1; i++) {
     a += `<button class="btn col s4 m2 blue-grey darken-3 waves-effect waves-light"`+
          `onclick="filterSelection('${arrayPath[i]}')">${arrayPath[i]}</button>`; 
}
```

Lo que me muestra: ('Prueba ') con un espacio:

```
<button class="btn col s4 m2 blue-grey darken-3 waves-effect waves-light __web-inspector-hide- 
shortcut__" onclick="filterSelection('Prueba ')">Prueba </button>
```

Lo que quiero: ('Prueba'):

```
<button class="btn col s4 m2 blue-grey darken-3 waves-effect waves-light __web-inspector-hide- 
shortcut__" onclick="filterSelection('Prueba')">Prueba </button>
```

El problema esta en que se agrega un espacio al final de Prueba asi 'Prueba ' y no lo quiero.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar [`string.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/Trim).

#### Ejemplo:

```js
var a = '';
let arrayPath = ['Prueba ', 'Otro '];
for (var i = 0; i < arrayPath.length-1; i++) {
     a += `<button class="btn col s4 m2 blue-grey darken-3 waves-effect waves-light"`+
          `onclick="filterSelection('${arrayPath[i].trim()}')">${arrayPath[i]}</button>`; 
}
console.log(a);
```

**PD**: Fijate que el último elemento del arreglo no se agrega y puede que sea o no un error.